# Understand Apple's DateCell program

Tags: ios, date

From here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/datecell/listings/MyTableViewController_m.html

The program runs. But I need to modify it so it will fit within my program. I can't get it to work even though I have copied verbatim. The issue is that as I click on start date, nothing happens. So as I am debugging, I'm noticing that my datePicker (in my program) is always nil. So I'm trying to figure out how apple does it, and they never initialize the datePicker. But it always has a non-nil value.

Where is apple allocing and initializing datePicker?

Also, I'm trying not to use storyboards, which Apple's program uses. (Though when I import the storyboard it doesn't help.)

Answer (score -1):

First of all there's a button "Download source code". It contains working project.

> Version 1.2, 2013-01-04: Upgraded for iOS 6.0, now using Automatic
>   Reference Counting (ARC) and storyboards, updated to adopt current
>   best practices for Objective-C.

This "about" info tells us you have to use deployment target 6.0 as the project uses storyboards with autolayouts, and you have to set "Automatic Reference Counting" to YES in your project properties.

All other guesses can be made only if you give us an error that you get.

P.S: I have downloaded the project and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, it works fine for me. But you didn't even read the question.

Comment: come on, datePicker is an outlet. It's initialized from nib. Outlets are never initialized in code

Comment: which nib, there are several. What role does the storyboard play?